# Android Jsoup - Elements are duplicated and skipped in foreach loop when using runOnUiThread

Tags: android, duplicates, jsoup

For the past day I've been trying to overcome this problem, yet I've had no success.
What happens is - I am getting all the values under a certain class using Jsoup (`getElementsByClass`) and then I'm running a foreach loop and in the end, I use `runOnUiThread` in order to update the views on the UI.

Long story, short - For some reason it goes okay for the first element, but from the 2nd element to the 10th element (there are 10), it just uses the value of the 10th element.
When I take off the runOnUiThread and use it as a regular function (not inside a thread, which I need), it works perfectly and doesn't skip/duplicate any element.

So, after this very long story (sorry that I didn't make it short), here is my code:

```
            counter = 1;

            AssetManager assets = getAssets();
            font = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "arial.ttf");

            //Loading 10 gags
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                Elements content = doc.getElementsByClass("Gag-Content");
                for(Element element : content) {
                            data = element.outerHtml();
                    if(data.indexOf("<iframe") == -1){
                        //Long ass random code here, in the end there are 2 variables: imageUrl & imageText

                        switch(counter){
                        case 1:
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                public void run() {
                                    final TextView text1;
                                    final ImageView image1;

                                    text1 = (TextView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                                    text1.setText(imageText);
                                    text1.setTypeface(font);

                                    image1 = (ImageView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                                    image1.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl));
                                }

                            });
                            /* final TextView text1;
                            final ImageView image1;

                            text1 = (TextView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                            text1.setText(imageText);
                            text1.setTypeface(font);

                            image1 = (ImageView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                            image1.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl)); */
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                public void run() {
                                    final TextView text2;
                                    final ImageView image2;

                                    text2 = (TextView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                                    text2.setText(imageText);
                                    text2.setTypeface(font);

                                    image2 = (ImageView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                                    image2.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl));
                                }
                            });

                            /* final TextView text2;
                            final ImageView image2;

                            text2 = (TextView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                            text2.setText(imageText);
                            text2.setTypeface(font);

                            image2 = (ImageView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                            image2.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl)); */
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                public void run() {
                                    final TextView text3;
                                    final ImageView image3;

                                    text3 = (TextView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                                    text3.setText(imageText);
                                    text3.setTypeface(font);

                                    image3 = (ImageView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
                                    image3.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl));
                                }
                            });

                            /* final TextView text3;
                            final ImageView image3;

                            text3 = (TextView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                            text3.setText(imageText);
                            text3.setTypeface(font);

                            image3 = (ImageView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
                            image3.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl)); */
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                public void run() {
                                    final TextView text4;
                                    final ImageView image4;

                                    text4 = (TextView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                                    text4.setText(imageText);
                                    text4.setTypeface(font);

                                    image4 = (ImageView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
                                    image4.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl));
                                }
                            });

                            /* final TextView text4;
                            final ImageView image4;

                            text4 = (TextView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                            text4.setText(imageText);
                            text4.setTypeface(font);

                            image4 = (ImageView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
                            image4.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl)); */
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                public void run() {
                                    final TextView text5;
                                    final ImageView image5;

                                    text5 = (TextView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.textView5);
                                    text5.setText(imageText);
                                    text5.setTypeface(font);

                                    image5 = (ImageView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
                                    image5.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl));
                                }
                            });

                            /* final TextView text5;
                            final ImageView image5;

                            text5 = (TextView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.textView5);
                            text5.setText(imageText);
                            text5.setTypeface(font);

                            image5 = (ImageView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
                            image5.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl)); */
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                public void run() {
                                    final TextView text6;
                                    final ImageView image6;

                                    text6 = (TextView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.textView6);
                                    text6.setText(imageText);
                                    text6.setTypeface(font);

                                    image6 = (ImageView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
                                    image6.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl));
                                }
                            });

                            /* final TextView text6;
                            final ImageView image6;

                            text6 = (TextView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.textView6);
                            text6.setText(imageText);
                            text6.setTypeface(font);

                            image6 = (ImageView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
                            image6.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl)); */
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                public void run() {
                                    final TextView text7;
                                    final ImageView image7;

                                    text7 = (TextView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.textView7);
                                    text7.setText(imageText);
                                    text7.setTypeface(font);

                                    image7 = (ImageView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
                                    image7.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl));
                                }
                            });

                            /* final TextView text7;
                            final ImageView image7;

                            text7 = (TextView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.textView7);
                            text7.setText(imageText);
                            text7.setTypeface(font);

                            image7 = (ImageView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
                            image7.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl)); */
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                public void run() {
                                    final TextView text8;
                                    final ImageView image8;

                                    text8 = (TextView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.textView8);
                                    text8.setText(imageText);
                                    text8.setTypeface(font);

                                    image8 = (ImageView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
                                    image8.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl));
                                }
                            });

                            /* final TextView text8;
                            final ImageView image8;

                            text8 = (TextView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.textView8);
                            text8.setText(imageText);
                            text8.setTypeface(font);

                            image8 = (ImageView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
                            image8.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl)); */
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                public void run() {
                                    final TextView text9;
                                    final ImageView image9;

                                    text9 = (TextView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.textView9);
                                    text9.setText(imageText);
                                    text9.setTypeface(font);

                                    image9 = (ImageView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
                                    image9.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl));
                                }
                            });

                            /* final TextView text9;
                            final ImageView image9;

                            text9 = (TextView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.textView9);
                            text9.setText(imageText);
                            text9.setTypeface(font);

                            image9 = (ImageView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
                            image9.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl)); */
                            break;
                        case 10:
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                public void run() {
                                    final TextView text10;
                                    final ImageView image10;

                                    text10 = (TextView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.textView10);
                                    text10.setText(imageText);
                                    text10.setTypeface(font);

                                    image10 = (ImageView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.imageView10);
                                    image10.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl));
                                }
                            });

                            /* final TextView text10;
                            final ImageView image10;

                            text10 = (TextView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.textView10);
                            text10.setText(imageText);
                            text10.setTypeface(font);

                            image10 = (ImageView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.imageView10);
                            image10.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl)); */
                            break;
                        }

                        counter++;
                        if(counter >= 11){
                            pd.dismiss();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by adding the values into an array, after the array was filled with the data I needed, I could load the data into the Views without any problems.